# Custom HDMI-to-( TFT or LVDS ) decoder/driver

Tags: pcb-design, lcd, ttl, lvds, tft

I am working on a custom-made handheld PCB based around a PI Compute Module 3+ and one of the hardest steps I have found is **how to include an HDMI-to-50pin-TTL driver on my PCB to run an LCD TFT 7" 1024x600 IPS panel.** First I have not found any available open-source driver board, either TTL, LVDS, or parallel RGB. The only alternative I have found is the [Adafruit TFP401](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tfp401-hdmi-slash-dvi-decoder-to-40-pin-ttl-display) board, but it is only compatible with Adafruit's low-resolution 40pin TTL screens. Higher resolutions TTL screens often come with 50 pin connectors. Also, I know the pi's MIPI display connector is closed-sourced and only works with pi's expensive and low-resolution screens.

**In summary, do you know any open-source HDMI-to-TTL or LVDS driver PCB design I can use for my project? If so, could you also share the schematics and compatible list of screens available for this driver? Thank you.**

Maybe I am looking at it from the wrong perspective. If you would have to add an LCD driver to your custom PCB, how would you do it?

Comment: If your display (by the way, what exact display? You never mention that!) already supports parallel RGB+HS/VS signalling, you don't even have to go through the trouble of using HDMI and converting stuff. [Try using the DPI (Parallel Display Interface)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/dpi/README.md) that the RPi already supports over its GPIO pins.

Comment: Hi, @RichardtheSpacecat . I did not specify the display because I want to know which interface is best to use before looking for it, but besides the interface, the specs are 1024x600 resolution, IPS preferably, TFT LVDS, or Parallel RGB interface. Also, I took a look at the link you mentioned and you are right, it is an awesome, and simple solution, but at the expense of losing all the GPIO pins, but, I don't mind losing them. Thank you for the advice, I think I will start there.

Comment: Were you able to find a HDMI-LVDS converter?